# Why can't I redirect to two input streams `0<` and `3<` in that order?

Tags: windows, cmd, io-redirection

When I try to redirect multiple files into multiple streams, like in the following example, everything works as expected:

```
3< stream3.txt 4< stream4.txt echo/
```

Something like that works also with more streams and files and other commands than `echo/` or even a functional block of code. Even using the reserved output streams `1` and `2` seem to work properly.

However, as soon as I do that with the following streams in the given order:

```
0< stream0.txt 3< stream3.txt echo/
```

The hosting command prompt instance is immediately closed.

When I change the order of the streams, it works fine again:

```
3< stream3.txt 0< stream0.txt echo/
```

So why is the `cmd` instance terminated unexpectedly when I try to input-redirect to stream `0` and `3` in that order?

I am using Windows 7 (x64).

---

When I open a new command prompt instance by `cmd` before I try to executed the aforementioned failing input redirection:

```
cmd
0< stream0.txt 3< stream3.txt echo/
```

I can read the appearing error message -- supposing the text files contain their base name followed by a line-break:

> ```
> 'stream3' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
> ```

When I do the following, I can see that both files are actually redirected:

```
cmd /V
0< stream0.txt 3< stream3.txt (set /P #="" & echo/!#!)

cmd /V
0< stream0.txt 3< stream3.txt (<&3 set /P #="" & echo/!#!)
```

Respective output:

```
stream0
```

And:

```
stream3
```

What the hell is going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**note**: This is a simplification of what happens inside `cmd` when the 
redirected command is executed.

Let's start with the indicated command

```
0< file1  3< file2 echo/
```

The command is parsed and a representation of the needed redirections is created in memory, some kind of table/list that will hold the information about the redirection: which handle is redirected, the old saved handle, to where the handle should point when redirected, ...

```
    Redirection requests
   ------------------------------- 
    redirect   saved   redirectTo
   +--------+--------+------------
R1 | 0                 file1
   |
R2 | 3                 file2
```

At this point (after parsing the command) no stream has been changed.

There is also a system table that handles where each of the file descriptors (in our case, the `cmd` streams) really points.

```
    File descriptors
   ------------------  
    points to
   +----------------- 
 0 | stdin
 1 | stdout
 2 | stderr
 3 |
 4 |
```

***note*** This is not exactly true, the underlying structure is a little more complex, but that way it is easier to see how it works

When the command is going to be executed, the internal `SetRedir` function is called. It iterates over the previous redirection request table saving existing handles and creating required new ones. The initial state is

```
    Redirection requests                         File descriptors
   -------------------------------              ------------------
    redirect   saved   redirectTo                points to
   +--------+--------+------------              +-----------------
R1 | 0                 file1                  0 | stdin
   |                                          1 | stdout
R2 | 3                 file2                  2 | stderr
                                              3 |
                                              4 |
```

First element from redirection request table (R1) is retrieved, the requests to redirect stream 0 to file1. It is necessary to save the current handle to later be able to restore it. For this operation the [`_dup()`](http://codewiki.wikidot.com/c:system-calls:dup) function is used. It will create an alias for the passed file descriptor (stream 0 in our code), using the smallest available file descriptor (stream 3 in previous table). After save operation and old handle close the situation is

```
   R1[saved] = _dup( R1[redirect] );
   _close( R1[redirect] );

    Redirection requests                         File descriptors
   -------------------------------              ------------------
    redirect   saved   redirectTo                points to
   +--------+--------+------------              +-----------------
R1 | 0        3        file1                  0 |          ---\
   |                                          1 | stdout      | 
R2 | 3                 file2                  2 | stderr      |
                                              3 | stdin   <<--/
                                              4 |
```

Once saved, the redirection is completed by opening the requested file and 
associating open file handle in the file descriptors table. In this case the
[`_dup2()`](http://codewiki.wikidot.com/c:system-calls:dup2) function handles the operation

```
 _dup2( CreateFile( R1[redirectTo] ), R1[redirect] );

    Redirection requests                         File descriptors
   -------------------------------              ------------------
    redirect   saved   redirectTo                points to
   +--------+--------+------------              +-----------------
R1 | 0        3        file1                  0 | file1   <<---
   |                                          1 | stdout
R2 | 3                 file2                  2 | stderr
                                              3 | stdin 
                                              4 |
```

The first redirection has been done. It is time to do the same operation with 
the second one. First, save the old handle using the `_dup()` function. This will associate the requested file descriptor (3) with the lowest available descriptor (4)

```
   R2[saved] = _dup( R2[redirect] );
   _close( R2[redirect] );

    Redirection requests                         File descriptors
   -------------------------------              ------------------
    redirect   saved   redirectTo                points to
   +--------+--------+------------              +-----------------
R1 | 0        3        file1                  0 | file1
   |                                          1 | stdout
R2 | 3        4        file2                  2 | stderr
                                              3 |         ---\
                                              4 | stdin  <<--/
```

The redirection is completed by opening the input file and associating it with the file descriptor

```
_dup2( CreateFile( R2[redirectTo] ), R2[redirect] );

    Redirection requests                         File descriptors
   -------------------------------              ------------------
    redirect   saved   redirectTo                points to
   +--------+--------+------------              +-----------------
R1 | 0        3        file1                  0 | file1
   |                                          1 | stdout
R2 | 3        4        file2                  2 | stderr
                                              3 | file2  <<---
                                              4 | stdin
```

The redirection has been completed and the command is executed with the stream 0 redirected to `file1` and the stream 3 redirected to `file2`.

Once done, it's time to revert the process. `ResetRedir()` function handles the operation. It uses again the `_dup2()` function to transfer the saved handle to the original file descriptor. Here the problem arises as the saved descriptor was changed

```
_dup2( R1[saved], R1[redirect] );
R1[saved] = null;

    Redirection requests                         File descriptors
   -------------------------------              ------------------
    redirect   saved   redirectTo                points to
   +--------+--------+------------              +-----------------
R1 | 0                 file1                  0 | file2  <<--\
   |                                          1 | stdout     |
R2 | 3        4        file2                  2 | stderr     |
                                              3 |         ---/
                                              4 | stdin
```

Now, the same operation is done with the second redirection

```
_dup2( R2[saved], R2[redirect] );
R2[saved] = null;

    Redirection requests                         File descriptors
   -------------------------------              ------------------
    redirect   saved   redirectTo                points to
   +--------+--------+------------              +-----------------
R1 | 0                 file1                  0 | file2
   |                                          1 | stdout
R2 | 3                 file2                  2 | stderr
                                              3 | stdin  <<--\
                                              4 |         ---/
```

Once the redirection has been removed the `&0` handle points to `file2` and the `stdin` stream is stored in `&3`. This can be tested as

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    >file1 echo This is file 1
    >file2 echo This is file 2

    echo Test 1 - trying to read from stdin after redirection
    cmd /v /c"( 0< file1 3< file2 echo - test1 ) &     set /p .=prompt & echo !.!"

    echo(
    echo(

    echo Test 2 - trying to read from stream 3 after redirection
    cmd /v /c"( 0< file1 3< file2 echo - test 2 ) & <&3 set /p .=prompt & echo !.!"
```

That will generate

```
W:\>testRedirection.cmd
Test 1 - trying to read from stdin after redirection
- test1
prompt This is file 2


Test 2 - trying to read from stream 3 after redirection
- test 2
prompt This is typed text
This is typed text

W:\>
```

It can be seen that in the first test, the `set /p` has read from `file2`, and in the second test, trying to read from `&3` the `stdin` stream can be reached.

Comment: Wow, excellent answer, +1!! This led me to another scenario that fails: `3< stream3.txt 0< stream0.txt 4< stream4.txt echo/`; since descriptor `3` is already occupied when `0` is processed, and `4` becomes the next free handle that is internally used then. In addition, I found out that there occurs an error with output redirection also: `1> stream1.txt 3> stream3.txt echo/` (`cmd` hangs until I enter `exit`), or `2> stream2.txt 3> stream3.txt echo/` (redirected handle `2` seems not to be closed properly); it looks like the internal process is the same for both input and output redirection...

Comment: So I think I could say as a rule that: *»After redirection of a predefined handle `0`/`1`/`2`, do not use the next free handle (neither for input nor for output redirection) for the same command line/block.«*

Comment: @aschipfl, input and output redirection are handled inside the same function, inside the same loop, it just accounts for handle replacement. The main difference is only how the new handle is retrieved. In your `1> stream1.txt 3> stream3.txt echo/` case, `cmd` is not hanged, it is just that `stdout` is being sent to `stream3.txt`. The general rule is to define redirections (when possible) from higher to lower streams.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a bug with the way the streams are being restored after the command has finished.  Consider the following batch file:

```
0< stream0.txt 3< stream3.txt findstr .

findstr .

<CON pause
```

The first `findstr` will output the content of `stream0.txt` as expected.

The second `findstr` will unexpectedly output the content of `stream3.txt`, indicating that stream 0 has unexpectedly become redirected.

When the batch file finishes, the command shell running it will exit too, because it sees an end of file on what is now the standard input stream.

---

Retrying one of my experiments in the light of [MC ND's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42425465/886887), I can now reproduce the same issue with a stream other than stream 3.  Consider `test7.cmd`:

```
0< stream0.txt 4< stream3.txt findstr .

findstr .

:done
<CON pause
```

Run as `cmd /c test7` or as `cmd /c test7 3< other.txt` it does not exhibit the unexpected behaviour, but run as `cmd /c "test7 3< other.txt"` it does.  (That was a facepalm moment; I could have discovered this yesterday if I'd thought about it more carefully.  Obviously the initial redirection has to be in the context of same command shell that is running the batch script.)

So the cause isn't "redirecting stream 3 as well as stream 0" but "redirecting the first free stream as well as stream 0". :-)

Comment: Nice finding, +1! The question for me is, why does this happen only with stream 3? it seems to me that stream 3 is not completely undefined or unused as [documented](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx); perhaps `cmd` uses it internally for something...

Comment: That was my thought, but none of the other variations I tried turned up anything.  It might be possible to work it out by reverse engineering `cmd.exe` but I don't have that kind of time. :-)