# How Consistent is Order-Ambiguous Shell I/O Redirection?

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, cmd, io-redirection

This fascinating post:

[How is this command legal ? “> file1 < file2 cat”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/356118/how-is-this-command-legal-file1-file2-cat)

highlights surprising behavior in a seemingly malformed `cat` call to "the shell" (a Linux shell, presumably BASH).  Basically, shells seem to be able to grab executables from ambiguous positions within in a series of strings and then use I/O redirection to streams / file descriptors.

The basic process per my understanding is:

1. Look for redirection patterns and [read them into or out of appropriate streams / file descriptors](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) (examples: `1>` (stdout)) (*This occurs prior to starting the executable process in the command!* (e.g. the `cat` call))
2. Find an executable process in the list of strings.
3. Start that executable process
4. Pause for process completion or continue (as needed) based kinds of output detected in step 1.

This leads to some surprising logic.  For instance in a new directory after executing `echo "dog" > cat`:

- `<cat cat >dog` : writes "dog" from file `cat` to `dog` using shell tool `cat`
- `<cat cat> cat cat` : overwrites first command, leaving a blank `cat` file (not sure what happens in the middle of the second command).
- `<cat cat> cat cat >dog 2>more` : creates empty files `dog` and `more`, overwrites `cat` file with empty file.
- `<cat >dog cat cat <dog >cat` (creates empty file `dog`, overwrites `cat` w/ empty file)
- `<cat cat >dog 2>much 1>more` : overwrites `cat` w/ an empty file; creates files `dog`/`more` each of which contain the string "dog", creates empty `much`

(The above list behavior was tested on `BASH` (v4.3.46).)

Now at some point the poor shell decides it's had enough.  For example, when faced with:

`<cat dog> cat cat >dog >cat`

It complains:

> bash: dog: command not found

But there's an extra surprise -- the command actually partially completed.  As in most of the above examples it's overwritten the file `cat` with a blank file and also created a blank file `dog`.

To better understand complex I/O redirection handling in the "[most popular Linux shells](http://www.tecmint.com/different-types-of-linux-shells/)" and CMD (the standard Windows shell):

1. `BASH` (Linux)
2. `TCSH` (Linux)
3. `KSH` (Linux)
4. `ZSH` (Linux)
5. `CMD` (Windows)

... is this kind of order-ambiguous I/O redirection parsing...

1. Supported by all of them? (I've only had time to test `BASH` (Linux) and `cmd` (Windows).)
2. Does it support all executables supported or just core shell utilities?
3. What are the rules used by these shells to handle sanitization/ordering of the streams/descriptors, particularly when parsing commands where the redirections appear ambiguous based upon the choice of substring (ex. `stuff.dat>1test.dat<2test.dat` where `1test.dat` and `2test.dat` are files)
4. To what degree are their parsing rules consistent between shells?
5. What determines failure of a command with complex I/O redirection patterns in these shells?

Comment: Concerning Windows `cmd`: [cmd.exe redirection operators order and position](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25559389)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For POSIX shells -- that is, shells which attempt to implement the Posix standard -- the parsing algorithm is actually reasonably simple, and also documented in that standard. That includes `bash`, `ksh` and `zsh` from your list (as well as others, such as `dash`) but not Windows `cmd`. `tcsh` is similar but not Posix.

Redirections are not "order ambiguous". They are parsed and executed left-to-right. The only possibly odd part is that they may be arbitrarily interleaved with the command and its arguments, but since every redirection is preceded by a redirection operator, no ambiguity results.

For [simple commands](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01), the procedure is roughly:

1. The command is split into words. Words preceded by redirection operators are redirections; those are removed from the command and saved for later processing.

   Note that the redirection operators are self-delimiting, so there is no difference whatsoever between `a> b`, `a >b`, and `a>b`. All of those are the word `a`, the redirection operator `>`, and the word `b`, and `>b` will be treated as a redirection. So the syntax `<a> b` might be confusing to a human reader (and should therefore be avoided) but it does not confuse the shell, which treats it as though it had been written in the more normal fashion as `<a >b`.
2. Leading words starting `ID=` are assignments (where `ID` is anything which looks like a variable name). These are also removed for later processing. Unlike redirections, these are the only recognised until the first word, if any, which is not an assignment.
3. The remaining words, if any, are expanded according to the expansion rules, which might involve splitting expanded words. The first word after expansion, if any, is the command, and the remaining words are command arguments.
4. The redirections are executed, left to right. Output redirections (`>foo`) create or truncate the named file; append redirections (`>>foo`) only create the file.
5. The assignments are expanded and applied. If there is a command, assignments are applied to the subshell environment the command will run in; otherwise, they are applied to the current shell environment.
6. If there is a command, it is executed with the command argument words being passed to it as the `argc/argv` arguments.

For example, the line `<cat cat> cat cat`, which seems to have confused you, is parsed left-to-right as:

- `<cat`, an input redirection
- `cat`, a command
- `>cat`, an output redirection
- `cat`, an argument

which results in the redirects `<cat` and `>cat` being executed before invoking the command `cat` with argument `cat`. The first redirect (`<cat`) will fail if the file `cat` did not exist in the current directory before executing that line so the second redirect (`>cat`) will only be executed if the file did exist; it will immediately truncate (empty) the file. Unless the current directory is in the PATH, the command `cat` will be executed from the file `/bin/cat`, which is a different file. Since an argument is supplied to the `cat` command, it will not use its standard input, so the `<cat` redirection will have no effect other than to cause the whole command to fail unless the file `cat` already existed. Since the file `cat` will be truncated before executing the command `cat cat`, nothing will be written to standard output, and the file `cat` will remain empty.

With respect to your last questions:

- These rules apply equally to all simple commands, whether built-in or not, aside from some details about error handling.
- The `2` in `>2foo` is not special, so `2foo` is a filename. FD duplication is indicated with the `>&` redirection operator; `>&2foo` is treated as an attempt to duplicate `2foo`, which is invalid because `2foo` is not an integer. Posix regards this as unspecified behaviour, so actual shells might do pretty well anything. See [Section 2.7.5](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_06) of the Posix shell specification for details (or at least the official line).
- A redirection could fail because of the non-existence of a file or because a file's permissions don't allow the action. As noted above, the redirections are executed left to right, which might have an effect in "complex" cases.

Comment: In terms of your parsing of `<cat cat> cat cat`, prior to all those commands I did `echo "dog" > cat`, so the file did exist & `cat cat` prints `dog` as expected.  So why is it being truncated in `BASH`?  Per my reading of your explanation, shouldn't it be reading in file `cat` to `stdin`, reading file `cat` to `stdout`?  Why is it overwriting the file `cat` as empty, as the first command should read in as non-empty?  Overall great explanation though, just the kind of info I was looking for, to supplement the examples in the Adv. BASH Scripting Guide.

Comment: @jason: it's being truncated when it is opened for output by the redirect. See my point 4. As I also mentioned, `cat` does not read from stdin if you give it arguments. See `man cat` for more info.

Comment: @jason: perhaps the point of confusion is that you have a model in which the command is evaluated in input order somehow, so that it has some responsibility for redirects, etc (as happens with the MS-DOS shell builtins). Unix shells do not work this way. The entire command line is parsed and an execution environment created before handing control to the command. That execution environment includes the indicated redirections, so they are not textually visible​ to the utility being executed; the utility simply reads and writes from standard streams.

Comment: AHHH I see it.. `<cat cat>` ... I misread `cat>` as `>cat`.  Makes sense now.  By the time the control program executes the file is wiped out...

Comment: @jason: `<cat >cat cat cat` would have identical effect. The redirections are removed from the command line and then first the redirections and then the remaining command words are processed left-to-right. So the precise interleaving doesn't matter; only the order of each set.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, linux is not my area, but `cmd` is. This is a `cmd` limited answer, you will have to join it with more information.

***Supported by all of them?***

Basic redirection operators (`<`, `>`, `>>`, `|`) were included in ms-dos 2.0 (still `command.com`) and have been available in all versions since then.

From windows 95 (just from memory) the handle duplicate operators (`>&`, `<&`) are also available.

More *exotic*/*non standard* operators present in [other shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159514) are not available.

***Does it support all executables supported or just core shell utilities?***

In `cmd` you can request the redirection of whatever executable or internal command you want, but the result will depend on executable (in console mode or not) hability to interact with `stdin`/`stdout`/`stderr`.

Ex.

- `timeout.exe`, a console subsytem executable does not allow input redirection
- `mshta.exe`, a graphic subsytem executable allows you to use the `FileSystemObject` to grab a reference to `StdOut` and write to it

***What are the rules used ...?***

`cmd` parsing rules are simple. Left to right. If the final parsed command makes sense (not unbalanced or explictly wrong) it is executed else you have a syntax error.

```
i = stdin input redirection
o = stdout output redirection
e = stderr output redirection
c = command to execute
a = arguments to the command

> file1 < file2 cat
^o      ^i      ^c   

<cat cat >dog
^i   ^c  ^o

<cat cat> cat cat
^i   ^c ^o    ^a

<cat cat> cat cat >dog 2>more
^i   ^c ^o    ^a  ^o   ^e       Second output cancels & replaces first one

<cat >dog cat cat <dog >cat
^i   ^o   ^c  ^a  ^i   ^o       Second i/o set cancels & replaces fist one

<cat cat >dog 2>much 1>more     Second output cancels & replaces first one
^i   ^c  ^o   ^e     ^o

<cat dog> cat cat >dog >cat     Multiple output replacement
^i   ^c ^o    ^a  ^o   ^o

stuff.dat>1test.dat<2test.dat
^c       ^o        ^i
```

After the command is parsed and it is determined that there is not any syntax error, the redirections have to be created before starting the command. If there is not any problem (input files exist, output files can be written) then the appropiate handles are asigned and the program/command is started (if it exists).

***To what degree are their parsing rules consistent between shells?***

`cmd.exe` rules are consistent between windows versions, and backward compatible with the syntax used in old versions of `command.com`.

Just an opinion, but, why should the shells have any kind of consistency between them? If all were consistent, why to have more than one?

***What determines failure of a command with complex I/O redirection patterns in these shells?***

How do you determine failure? How do you determine sucess? The shell will try to do what you asked, not what you wanted. And even clear commands can behave in a priori [unspected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42380192/2861476) ways.

`cmd` [parses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/2861476) commands and converts them into an internal representation. In this representation the data relative to the command requested is separated from the redirection information. Both the "command part" and the "redirection part" must be syntactically correct (from the parser point of view) before even starting to execute anything.

When the command is about to be executed, the redirection request is [processed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41324747/2861476), adquiring the required files/handles. If everything can be established then the command is executed inside the created context.

So, failure can be

- A syntax problem (while parsing)
- A resource adquisition problem (while creating the redirection context, before starting command execution)
- A rights/hardware problem (during execution of the command)

Comment: On consistency between shells I don't have a strong opinion -- I just was interested in the extent of the consistency give that in my tests, for the couple of examples I tried in `CMD` above it was working like `BASH`.  As far as "failure" I was quantifying it as when the command produced an error that caused the line to terminate without reading / acting on all arguments, not "failure" from the perspective of producing an unexpected result (as I expected the unexpected).  I get what you mean, though, the term is ambiguous.  Hopefully that clarifies.

Comment: BTW this is an incredible answer.  I wish I could mark two correct answers.  Thank you... very enlightening, and I think people will come across this and learn a lot.