# Stream 3 handle redirection causes output flood

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, io-redirection

I was playing with `wmic` when this command

```
wmic<nul 3>nul
```

produced this:

[image]

The strange thing is, ***any*** command will work, but only stream 3 causes the output flood.
I googled and searched on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcmd%5D%20output%20flood) "cmd output flood" and cannot find any duplicates nor any results.
Question: Why only stream 3 works?

Update: Likewise,

```
>con 3<con :
```

**completely** disables `STDOUT`!

Comment: Perhaps this is somehow linked to a [problem I once encountered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42380192)...

Comment: hang on while i read the answer...

Comment: I don't know if powershell's redirection is the same, but I was able to find this which may be the answer... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7

Comment: @aschipfl, it is almost exactly the same problem. In this case, after undoing the redirection, stream 0 points to `nul` stream and when the `cmd` prompt tries to read a new command it reads from `nul` (does not fail, just reads nothing), shows prompt again, read again,  ... In your case stream 0 ended pointing to a file and when the end of file was reached the `cmd` read operation failed causing the `cmd` instance to close.

Comment: So my guess was right, @MCND, thanks! Now I can't await your answer... ;-)

Comment: @aschipfl, I think I'm missing something. It would be the same answer I already wrote for your question.

Comment: @MCND, so would you consider this question as a duplicate of mine? I don't want to vote since it's going to be closed immediately due to my batch patch...

Comment: @aschipfl, I'm in the same case, one vote closes the question. This question is not a duplicate of yours (different behaviour), but the answer is the same. In those cases, after being pointed to the answer, I think it is the OP who should decide to close the question or not.

Comment: @aschipfl, I'm still wondering whether or not to close the question, but I've included an answer with the content of the comment aboout the different behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that, [as pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61934916/stream-3-handle-redirection-causes-output-flood?noredirect=1#comment109542997_61934916) by aschipfl, [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42425465/2861476) to [their question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42380192/2861476) explains what the source of the problem is.

Please refer to them for the inner details, this answer is just a summary to explain the different behaviour.

- When a redirection is created the code inside `cmd` handling this task tries to avoid problems saving the original handles to the streams that are being redirected so the redirection process can be reverted.
- But the way the used function (standard `_dup()`) works and the order used when creating the redirection can alter the internal structures used in such a way that at the end the code reversing the redirection uses wrong information.

In short:

```
<nul 3<nul wmic
```

- `<nul` saves the `stdin` handle in `&3` and assigns `nul` stream to `&0`
- `3<nul` saves the handle inside `&3` into `&4` and assigns `nul` stream to `&3`
- `wmic` is executed. As it is reading from `nul` (assigned to `&0`) it can not read anything and ends.
- `&0` is restored from `&3` where it was saved, BUT now `&3` points to `nul`
- `&3` is restored from `&4`. Now it points to the original `stdin`

In the original aschipfl's question the observed behaviour was command prompt closing. After code execution

```
< file1 3< file2 echo/
```

the redirection cancel process leaves `stdin` stream pointing to a disk file (`file2`). `cmd` starts to read this file for commands to execute (as it normally does from `stdin`) and at end of file the read operation fails and the `cmd` instance ends. If you want a convoluted way of seeing it in work to start notepad you can try

```
( >file1 echo notepad ) & ( <nul 3<file1 break )
```

But in this question the behaviour is different because the stream assigned to `&3`, that will be copied to `stdin` once the redirection is reverted, is not a disk file but `nul`

```
<nul 3<nul echo/
```

1. Once the command is executed and redirections are reverted `stdin` stream is associated with `nul` device
2. `cmd` shows the prompt and tries to retrieve a new command reading from `nul`
3. The read operation ends but does not retrieve anything so `cmd` does not execute anything
4. goto 2

The question "*Why only stream 3 works?*" (in the sense of it does not work ;) ) is not correct. You can do something like

```
1>file1 <nul 4<nul echo/
```

and get the same result using different streams. Or you can do

```
 3<nul <nul echo/
```

and it will work (in the sense of it works).

The order in which you request the redirection of the streams, how they are handled by `cmd` internal code and the existence of still active previous redirections can decide the success or failure of the command.

Comment: Why is it when you run `"<nul 3<nul wmic"` from `cmd /c` like `cmd /c "<nul 3<nul wmic"` it runs properly and as intended? Same thing with `cmd /c "wmic<nul 3>nul"`, it just prints out `wmic:root\cli>` like it should normally.

Comment: @NekoMusume, why should it behave in a different way than what you see? You ask for a command in a separate `cmd` instance, it is executed and the separate `cmd` instance ends.

Comment: I see... Thank you for your insight